# Qual a definição do termo acoplamento?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, arquitetura-de-software, design-pattern, modelagem

Qual o significado dos termos alto/baixo acoplamento em desenvolvimento de sistemas orientados a objetos ou [programação orientada a objetos (POO)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_a_objetos)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Conceito**

- Em um aspecto global acoplamento é o grau de dependência entre dois
  "artefatos". Onde artefatos podem ser entidades, métodos, componente,
  tabelas, enfim qualquer coisa que esteja na outra.
- **Acoplamento baixo** - é quando um "artefato", tem pouco ou nada de
  dependência em relação aos outros.
- **Acoplamento alto** - é o inverso do baixo obviamente, sendo quando um
  "artefato" tem uma grande dependência em relação a outro.

**Boas Práticas (Design Principle)**

- Alto acoplamento não é considerado uma boa prática de programação,
  onde seus componentes, "artefatos", terão um alto grau de dependência,
  tornando mais difícil de manter e testar.*¹
- Já o baixo acoplamento é considerado uma boa prática de programação (loose coupling),
  já que com ele você mantem seus componentes, "artefatos", menos
  dependentes um dos outros, tendo maior rastreabilidade e
  testabilidade.*¹

> *¹ Mas isso trata-se apenas de Boas Práticas (princípio de design), não quer dizer que você não possa utilizar alto grau acoplamento em seu projeto, por que ele é inevitável em alguns casos. Só se deve ter o cuidado de manter seu projeto com o menor grau de acoplamento possível.

**Exemplos**

- Um exemplo corriqueiro de alto acoplamento é **herança**, onde sua
  entidade não consegue existir sem a sua entidade base. Em modelagem esse é
  considerado o grau mais alto de acoplamento. Mas nem por isso deve deixar
  de ser utilizado, somente deve ser utilizado com maior moderação,
  sempre analisando se é realmente necessário esse alto grau de
  acoplamento.
- Uma boa prática para reduzir o acoplamento é a utilização de outros
  padrões, como por exemplo Injeção de Dependencia ([dependency
  injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)), que ajuda a reduzir o dependência entre camadas,
  entidades ou módulos.
- Para reduzir o acoplamento também é aconselhável a analise de suas
  dependências, verificando se elas possam ser removidas, ou trocadas
  por outra com um grau de dependência menor (por exemplo, trocar uma
  herança por uma agregação), isso já vai melhorar a rastreabilidade e
  testabilidade de seu projeto.

**Considerações**

O acoplamento é necessário, entre diferentes módulos, o que os padrões pregam é que seja o menor possível, sempre avaliando se é necessário criar determinada dependência ou se pode ser substituída por uma dependência menor.

> Obs.: O conceito de acoplamento é independente de linguagem de programação ou tecnologia utilizada em seu projeto. É questão de **boas práticas**.

Comment: @Piovezan, sua edição e descrição dela foi tão boa que devia virar comentário para deixar claro para todo mundo.

Comment: Sim @bigown! Também li o comentário da edição e vi que esse erro persistiu na resposta por mais de um ano, nem tinha conhecimento deste termo "Design Principle", mas está correto isso não pode ser um Design Pattern, pois é algo mais abstrato que não pode ser feito como um bolo. Então acredito que o termo "Design Principle" é muito mais adequado. Obrigado pela edição @Piovezan.

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado pelo feedback. Não sei se em todas as edições compensa esse nível de detalhe, coloquei mais por se tratar de um assunto potencialmente espinhoso (a definição de _design pattern_) e que poderia resultar em discussões se não fosse devidamente justificado.

Answer (score 17):

Acoplamento é o quanto uma classe sabe de outra classe.

O ideal é que haja baixo acoplamento entre as classes pois as classes devem ser especialistas para o serviço o qual elas foram designadas.

O baixo acoplamento também é desejado pois fica mais fácil identificar problemas relativos a classe, que é um dos princípios do paradigma da orientação a objetos.

**EDIT**

"Saber de outra classe" significa que a classe em questão usa métodos e/ou atributos de alguma outra classe. Isso faz com que a classe dependa da outra classe, ou seja, o comportamento da classe estará diretamente ligado ao comportamento da outra.

O alto acoplamento entre as classes torna difícil a manutenção delas, pois imagine, cada vez que você editar uma classe você também estará alterando o comportamento das classes que estão acopladas com ela, se você não tiver conhecimento das classes acopladas você estará correndo um grande risco de estar inserindo *bugs* e comportamentos inesperados ao seu programa.

Answer (score 12):

Falaram tanto da definição, vou falar então um pouco sobre Acoplamento fraco:

Introdução

Acoplamento fraco é um dos principais requisitos para se construir software orientado a objetos (OO) de qualidade. O acoplamento fraco mede o quanto uma classe, depende de, ou está relacionada a, outra classe ou subsistema. A capacidade de uma classe em herdar o comportamento de outra(s) é uma das principais características do paradigma OO. A principal vantagem é poder criar novas classes quase de graça, aproveitando o código de outra. Esse artigo discute esses dois conceitos e mostra porque a herança, em geral, ajuda a comprometer o acoplamento fraco.

Acoplamento fraco

Uma classe com acoplamento forte depende muito (em geral sem necessidade) de outras. Isso pode conduzir aos seguintes problemas [Larman]:

·         classes difíceis de aproveitar tendo em vista que sempre que esta for utilizada todas as outras das quais ela depende devem estar presentes;

·         alterações nas classes relacionadas podem forçar mudanças locais e

·         são difíceis de compreender isoladamente.

Formas comuns de acoplamento ocorrem através de: variáveis de instância, variáveis locais a métodos ou de seus argumentos, chamada de serviços em outra classe, uma classe deriva direta ou indiretamente de outra ou uma classe implementa uma determinada interface. Resumindo, sempre que uma classe referencia um outro tipo em qualquer uma das circunstâncias acima está ocorrendo acoplamento. Considere o código:

```
public class X
{
    private ClasseConcretaY var1;
void M1(ClasseConcretaW var2 ) { … }
}
```

Existem dois pontos principais de acoplamento, na variável de instância var1, que é do tipo ClasseConcretaY, e no argumento var2, que é do tipo ClasseConcretaW. Nestas duas partes do código a classe X referencia outras duas classes concretas. Isso significa que, sempre que esta classe for utilizada, as outras duas deverão estar disponíveis no espaço de nomes do programa. No caso de Java, o(s) pacote(s) onde estas se encontram deverá(ão) estar no classpath.

Mas, referenciar outras classes sempre causa problemas de acoplamento? A resposta é, depende! Referenciar classes estáveis e disseminadas raramente é um problema. Por exemplo, utilizar o pacote java.util num programa em Java dificilmente causará problemas futuros de acoplamento, uma vez que qualquer ambiente de execução Java contém essa biblioteca. O problema está em classes instáveis, pouco conhecidas, ou seja, nas classes que são criadas para atender os problemas específicos dos projetos.

Como diminuir o acoplamento?

Uma regra geral para diminuir o acoplamento é “programar para uma interface e não para uma implementação” [Gamma]. No exemplo acima isso significa substituir as declarações das classes concretas por declarações de interfaces. Fazendo isso desacopla-se o código de uma implementação específica, tornando-o dependente apenas de uma interface. Essa não é a solução definitiva, um bom projeto com boas atribuições de responsabilidades é crucial, porém ajuda muito. É mais fácil compreender isoladamente uma classe que referencia apenas interfaces e mais [Gamma]:

os clientes (usuários da classe) permanecem sem conhecimento dos tipos específicos dos objetos que eles usam, contanto que os objetos tenham aderência à interface que os clientes esperam,
os clientes permanecem sem conhecimento das classes que implementam estes objetos; eles somente têm conhecimento das classes abstratas que definem a interface.

Fonte: http://www.devmedia.com.br/acoplamento-fraco-x-heranca/3714