# Quando e como usar protocolos e delegates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvc, swift

Alguém poderia por favor me explicar em que situação e como usar delegates e protocolos, estou um pouco confuso quando ao que li por aí, Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um exemplo prático e muito comum de ser usado é quando há a necessidade de voltar com dados de uma **view B** que foi aberta por outra **view A**. Um dos métodos de comunicação entre estas duas classe, além de protocolos e *delegates*, são também as [`Notifications`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Notification.html) e [`KVO (Key-value Observing)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html).

Mas utilizando da sua dúvida, supondo que eu tenha um aplicativo em que uma primeira view **FormViewController** tenha uma informação para ser preenchida com as coordenadas de um local do mapa presente em uma view **MapViewController**, eu crio meu protocolo com a definição de um método que retorne essa informação (utilizando **Swift**, logo após os *imports*):

```
protocol MapSelectorDelegate {
    func coordinateSelected(coordinate: CLLocation)
}
```

E uma propriedade que irá receber a referência para este protocolo, o objeto "delegador":

```
var delegate: MapSelectorDelegate?
```

Ainda nesta view, quando a coordenada for selecionada, é neste momento que você executa o método que definimos no protocolo, quando o usuário tocar em um ponto do mapa, por exemplo.

```
delegate.coordinateSelected(coordinate)
```

A implementação deste método está na classe anterior, que chamei de **FormViewController**, onde temos definido o protocolo no cabeçalho da classe:

```
class FormViewController: UIViewController, MapSelectorDelegate
```

E atribuído como o "delegador" quando dei um "push" na view do mapa através de `segue`:

```
let mapViewController = segue.destinationViewController as MapViewController
mapViewController.delegate = self
```

E por fim, a implementação do método `delegate`, que é obrigatório já que não o criamos como `optional`:

```
func coordinateSelected(coordinate: CLLocation) {
    // Fazer o que quiser com as coordenadas
}
```

Comment: Muito boa explicação. Fica fácil entender com os exemplos de duas views. Obrigado!

Answer (score 7):

## Objective-C

Em Objective-C há dois tipos de [protocolos](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html): Formais e Informais

### Protocolos Informais

Um protocolo informal é uma categoria de `NSObject` normalmente sem implementação, ou seja, todas as classes que herdarem de `NSObject` estarão em conformidade com esse protocolo informal. Os métodos em protocolos informais são sempre opcionais. Protocolos informais são um recurso antigo da linguagem e caíram em desuso com a adição de `@optional` no Objective-C 2.0.

**Mas o que são categorias?**

> De forma resumida [`Category`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) é uma forma de se adicionar métodos a classes já existentes sem ter de usar herança. A *magia* das categorias é que elas podem ser usadas até mesmo em classes que você não possui o código fonte.

### Protocolos Formais

Um protocolo é uma espécie de acordo que diz quais métodos uma classe deve implementar para entrar em conformidade. Em teoria uma classe está em conformidade com um dado protocolo quando implementa todos os seus métodos não opcionais. Em Cocoa os exemplos mais de comum de protocolos são [`Delegate`s e `DataSource`s](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11-SW1). Protocolos são  extremamente úteis pois ajudam a manter um [baixo acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11100/3907) das classes. **Protocolos são usados para garantir que um objeto implementa certos métodos ser necessário conhece-lo.**

#### Delegate

Delegação é um *[padrão de projeto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)* simples mas extremamente poderoso usado quando um objeto age no lugar de um outro ou junto com ele. Delegar uma ação é perguntar para outro objeto como uma certa ação deve ser realizada. Um exemplo clássico de método de um delegate é o [`didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) do [`UITableViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/UITableViewDelegate) que informa que uma célula foi selecionada. **Delegação é usado quando se quer delegar uma tarefa ou 'perguntar' algo para outro objeto.**

#### Data Source

Data Sources lembram muito delegates mas servem para fornecer dados para um objeto. Um exemplo clássico de método de um data source é o [`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) também da [`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/UITableViewDataSource) que espera que um [`UITableViewCell*`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/UITableViewDataSource) seja retornado para que a célula referenciada seja exibida na tela.

## Swift

Em Swift o conceito é análogo no entanto protocolos informais em Swift não são mencionados em nenhum lugar da documentação. Outra coisa extremamente interessante é que qualquer tipo pode entrar em conformidade com um protocolo em Swift com isso é possível fazer códigos incrivelmente intuitivos com protocolos como [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Equatable.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH17-SW1), [Comparable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Comparable.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH16-SW1) e [Printable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Printable.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH11-SW1).

**Mas e as categorias em Swift?**

> Swift possui algo ainda mais *mágico*: [`Extension`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)s. De acordo com a documentação extensions permitem:
>
> - Adicionar propriedades computadas e propriedades computadas estáticas
> - Definir novos métodos de instância e métodos de tipo *(sim, podemos estender tipos primitivos!)*
> - Criar novos inicializadores
> - Definir [subscripts](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html)
> - Definir e usar novos [tipos aninhados](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/NestedTypes.html)
> - Fazer um tipo existente entrar em conformidade com um protocolo

Comment: Interessante. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

**Delegates e MVC do IOS**

Delegation, como já foi dito em outras respostas é um *design pattern* poderoso no qual um objeto age no lugar ou em coordenação com outro. No MVC (Model-View-Controller) da Apple delegates são tipicamente controllers e são, em geral, usados para realizar a comunicação cega das *views* com seu Controller.

O controller tem acesso direto (conhece) seu Model e suas Views, mas as Views e o Model não conhecem seu controller, porém, em certos momentos precisam se comunicar de volta com ele e **fazem isso através de uma comunicação cega**. O Model através da central de notificações e as views através de target-actions (para eventos como por exemplo o touch de um botão), **e delegates**.

Quando existe mais de um MVC (um controller que dispara outro controller), **esse último controller é tratado pelo primeiro também como se fosse uma view** (ou seja, o controller tratado como view não conhece o controller mais externo e se comunica com ele através de delegate).

**Como funciona**

A comunicação cega faz com que a view (ou objeto tratado como view) saiba que tem um delegate, mas não exatamente seu tipo, e que possa chamar os métodos desse delegate quando precisar. Em geral os métodos que a View precisará chamar tem o sentido de DID, SHOULD ou WILL. O próprio IOS usa delegates, como por exemplo em uma de suas views, a UITextField. Assim que essa view identifica que o usuário acabou de editá-la, chama o método `func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)`de seu delegate para informá-lo.

Com esse mecanismo é simples, por exemplo, "desplugar" e "plugar" view controllers usando o storyboard, já que são independentes (não conhecem tipo de seu delegate, só sabem que tem um) e é possível utilizar as views em diferentes view-controllers, como no caso do UITextfield.

**Protocols**

Protocolos são como contratos independentes que classes podem seguir. Se uma classe está em conformidade com um certo protocolo, então precisa implementar os métodos que forem obrigatórios indicados nesse protocolo. Os protocolos podem ser utilizados em conjunto com delegates. O objeto que possui um delegate sabe que possui alguém para lidar com certas situações (o delegate) mas não o seu tipo, porém sabe que esse objeto deveria estar de acordo com um protocolo, ou seja que implementa certos métodos e possui certas propriedades.

Por exemplo, para tornar a UITableView o mais "reusável" possível, todas as decisões relativas a seus dados devem ser delegados para outro objeto (no caso um datasource, que é o mesmo que um delegate porém com o propósito de fornecer dados).

Um controller que possui uma tableView deve, portanto, estar em conformidade com o UITableViewDataSource protocol. Isso indica que ele deve implementar métodos que irão ser chamados pela tableView como "qual o dado para a célula tal". Se o controller está em conformidade com o protocolo e não implementa os métodos obrigatórios, então o XCode exibirá um erro.

**Como usar**

Da mesma forma que a Apple usa delegates e protocols para organizar seu código e tornar suas classes mais independentes e "reusáveis" você também está livre para usá-los. Em geral, irá usá-los para garantir a comunicação cega entre Views, ou objetos tratados como Views, e seu Controller.

Entendendo o MVC da Apple fica claro quando usá-los.